# python - Letters Breaking Code

Tags: python

In need help with this code,

```
print("Please enter NUMBER PLATE")
Num_plate = (input())
#Asks for and stores number plate

print ("Please enter DISTANCE")
Dist = (float(input()))
#Asks for and stores distance

print ("Please enter SPEED LIMIT")
Speed_lim = (float(input()))
#Asks for and stores speed limit

print ("Please enter FINISH time")
End = (float(input()))
#Asks for and stores end time
```

Whenever i input letters i comes up with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Average Speed Camera Code.py", line 17, in <module>
    Dist = (float(input()))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'fg'
```

Comment: Are you sure you are trying input with only numeric characters ? The error generally means that you are trying to input a alphanumeric string which is not convertible to `float`.

Comment: The format you are entering the finish time in, can not be converted to a float. What are you typing there?

Answer (score 0):

`float()` tries to convert the `input()` to a [float](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). If your input is `fg` this will fail because its not a number. If you want to have text you need to use `str()`, in python3 this would not be needed as `input()` already returns a string by default.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in error you are trying to enter charachters "fg" which are not convertible to float. When you enter the expected input, you will not get this error.

Also I see you are using separate print statements to print statements to standard output. Instead of this you can just put statement in the input, like this:

```
Num_plate = input("Please enter NUMBER PLATE")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're getting at is that you'd rather the code didn't crash on invalid input? For that you'll need some error handling. If you want to force a valid input something like:

```
print ("Please enter DISTANCE")
while True:
    try:
        Dist = (float(input()))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid input!")
```

if you were feeling flash you could wrap this up in a re-usable function to reduce repetition for the other calls.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I wanted :D ty :)

Comment: Please make sure you accept the answer (the tick to the left of the answer) if it was the one that worked for you. Glad to help.